# How to Download object from google cloud storage to Local Directory using JSON API

Tags: api, path, google-cloud-storage

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
-o "[SAVE_TO_LOCATION]" \
"https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[OBJECT_NAME]?alt=media"
```

I don't know where we need to give the local directory(SAVE_TO_LOCATION) path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.List the bucket

```
gsutil ls gs://your-bucket
#gs://your-bucket/file
```

2.Assuming that you want to download the blob `gs://your-bucket/file` to `/home/user/file`

```
curl -X GET   -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"   -o "/home/user/file"   "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/your-bucket/o/file?alt=media"
```

3.Check if the file was downloaded

```
cat /home/user/file
```

Comment: sorry, still not understand.where we need to add the path (/home/user/file).I am using OAuth 2.0 Playground.are we need to add (-o "/home/user/file") in header.assume i have a path in my local directory (C:\Users\Sudheer\Desktop\GCP), so how can i add this path.also is there any possible way to transfer file from cloud storage to VM instence folder using API.one thing i don't want to use console shell.all i need is using API.

Comment: From my understanding is not possible with the api. I checked the official api [Objects: get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get?apix_params=%7B%22bucket%22%3A%22temprun%22%2C%22object%22%3A%22file%22%2C%22alt%22%3A%22json%22%7D). This api return the object data when set  `alt media`. Therefore, you should call the API from the VM instance. Please check [Transferring files to instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files)

Comment: Ok, understand. actually I can able to download and upload files in .Net core programmatically using Google cloud library. but I tried to get using API calls.so I will try to get files based on object data. I just started using Google cloud. Thanks.